# Make an animation run right away after change a variable

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I have 2 state A and B in animation window, if the variable Y is changed to true it will transit from state A to B, but when  variable Y has been changed the value, it wait for the state A  to complete then it transit to state B. I don't want that, I want the state A transit to B right away after I change the variable Y.

Comment: How are you doing your transition?

Comment: Please, read tag descriptions before using them. `unity` tag has nothing to do with the Unity game engine.

Comment: right click on state A and make transition to state B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Unity Editor, on the Animator window, select the transition from A to B and unmark the Atomic checkbox on the Inspector window.

This [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/787976/what-can-interrupt-a-non-atomic-transition-in-the.html) gives a simple explanation on how atomic transitions work

Comment: could you please point me where the Atomic checkbox is, I can't see it.

Comment: I don't have enought reputation to add an image to my answer so I uploaded it to my  google drive. You can see it on this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0swTjoFGhlhRGpucGMtLUtQeWs&authuser=0